# Find incorrect data from SQL

Tags: sql

As you can see below, data is increasing except 5th row. How can I find that data using SQL code?

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 102.312 |
| 2 | 103.412 |
| 3 | 104.621 |
| 4 | 105.512 |
| 5 | 102.561 |
| 6 | 106.632 |
| 7 | 107.742 |

Comment: You've tagged with many different databases.  Which one are you actually using?  Also, is this _text_ data?  If not, is that thousands separator dot specific to your locale?

Comment: Please only tag the DBMS you are using. How do you dertermine what is the fith row? I see that you numbered the rows you are showing us, but is there actually a column representing this order? Like `id` in Akina's edit?

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add only one tag for the DBMS you are really working with.

Comment: If the sixth row's value were 104.999, it would be greater than the fith row's value, but still less than the fourth row's value. Would you want to show this row in your results or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need a column to represent the order you want to apply. Let's say there is a column `id` in your table we can use for this. Such a column is usually not guaranteed to be consecutive (i.e. without gaps).

The easiest way to find the rows where the value is not greater than the previous value is to use `LAG` which should be available in most modern DBMS. (For MySQL `LAG`  is available as of version 8).

```
select *
from
(
  select t.*, lag(value) over (order by id) as previous_value from mytable t
) x
where value <= previous_value
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id AS wrong_row_id
FROM src t1
JOIN src t2 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1 
           AND t1.value < t2.value
```

if `id` values are not consecutive then

```
SELECT t1.id AS wrong_row_id
FROM src t1
JOIN src t2 ON t1.id > t2.id
           AND t1.value < t2.value
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM src t3
                   WHERE t1.id > t3.id AND t3.id > t2.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
select id, value
  from your_Table t 
 where exists 
       (select 1 from your_Table tt
         where tt.id < t.id and tt.value > t.value)
```